# NodeJS socket.io throws error Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using WAMP offline server and I installed NodeJS for my chat application. The chat application works fine but I receive this error in my console

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/socket.io/1/websocket/1300942723267398434' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Even though the application works fine, but I don't want to see that error and I believe if I upload my application to a live server, it won't work perfectly because of this error.

I have tried many solutions from SO but it didn't work for me:

- [Socket.io - failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665840/socket-io-failed-connection-closed-before-receiving-a-handshake-response)
- [WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977916/websocket-connection-to-ws-localhost3000-failed-connection-closed-before)
- [Socket.io: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209713/socket-io-connection-closed-before-receiving-a-handshake-response)

Below is my back end code

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000),
dns = require('dns'),
express = require('express'),
mysql = require('mysql');
```

On the front end:

```
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution... The error came as a result of unsecured connection `http` after creating a secured connection to the server, the application work fine